# Unmanaged to Managed returning object that contains BOOL

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am using PInvoke in C# to call a function in a C++ DLL. The returned object contains a bool, but the value is never correct. I've read several articles on this that indicate a C++ bool is 1 byte while in C# a bool is 4 bytes. I've also seen examples on how to overcome this problem when a function returns a bool, but my function is returning an object that contains a bool. I'm not finding any articles that show how to handle this situation.

For example, I have two structs. One for input to the unmanaged DLL's function and one that defines the output:

```
public struct MyInput
{
    public int id;
    public string ModelNumber;
}

public struct MyOutput
{
    public int SomeValue;
    public double AnotherValue;
    public bool IsValid;
}

[DllImport("MyUnmanaged.dll", EntryPoint = "?Unit@@YA?AUMyOutput@@UMyInput@@@Z")]
    public static extern MyOutput Unit(ref MyInput UnitInput);
```

MyOutput doesn't work as defined above because the signature is invalid. So I changed IsValid to:

```
public int IsValid;
```

This took care of the invalid signature error, but the value of IsValid isn't a 0 or 1 like I would expect. Instead it is -858993664. I've also tried changing to byte, but then the returned value is always 0.

I don't understand how to marshal the bool inside of the MyOutput struct or how to define it so that I get a valid bool - a 1 or a 0.

Btw, I don't have any control of the unmanaged DLL...

Can someone provide me with an idea of how to define the bool inside of the MyOutput struct?

**EDIT**

All I was given is the .DLL and .h for the unmanaged DLL. In the .h, the bool in question is defined as:

```
bool IsValid;
```

Comment: `BOOL` and `bool` are distinct types, yet you use them interchangeably. Which is it? How exactly is `MyOutput` defined on the C++ side? And are the other values you get in `MyOutput` (up to the boolean) correct, or do they also show bogus values?

Comment: @hvd, all of the other values returned are completely valid. Actually there are about 30 or so values. The .h for the unmanaged DLL shows the bool as `bool IsValid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [online demangler](http://demangler.com/), your unmanaged function has this signature:

```
struct MyOutput __cdecl Unit(struct MyInput)
```

So your C# declaration should be:

```
[DllImport("MyUnmanaged.dll", EntryPoint = "?Unit@@YA?AUMyOutput@@UMyInput@@@Z",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern MyOutput Unit(MyInput UnitInput);
```

In other words you were using the wrong calling convention, and passing the parameter by `ref` rather than by value.

You have also discovered that your return value struct type cannot be marshalled because it contains a `bool` field. You'll need to change that to `byte` or `int` depending on what the unmanaged struct declaration is. It looks like, based on your edits, that the header file declares it as `bool`, which is a single byte type, so you should use `byte`.

Comment: this is very useful information. I made this change to the way I am calling the DLL function. It still works as it did previously, but I'm sure your answer is correct. I'm still receiving a `0` (zero) for the bool (defined in my output struct as byte). I'm not asking you for clarification on that, but if you might now why the return value is always zero it would be helpful. The DLL was written by an engineer. It is used by one other developer who has had success in getting a return value of 1/0 as it should. I think the difference is his implementation is x86, mine is x64.

Comment: I can't say any more given the information available to me

Answer (score 2):

-858993664 == 0xcccccc00.  Sure, this is the kind of value you'd expect to get when you don't use `byte` or apply the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]` attribute on the member.  Clearly you are using the debug build of that DLL, it initializes memory to 0xcccccccc.

So you are *really* getting a `false` value for IsValid.  Of course there's no reasonable guess you could get here why the native code is unhappy.  You'll need to talk to the C programmer to learn more about it.  You'll also need his help when it is time to deploy your program, you can't ship the debug build of that DLL.

Comment: I set the member to a byte and decorated it with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1]`. Should I do both? The value is always zero now, which I assume means `False`? Note that my example renamed method members. The bool is only a flag that says whether or not a product model is within the input tolerances. At this point I see nothing but a zero for every returned result which also seems wrong. I should be seeing true AND false results.

Comment: Asked and answered.  You are getting a *false*, verified in three different ways, it is reliable.  Pick up the phone and call the C programmer to ask how you get a happy *true*.  If he doesn't want to help then ask for the source code so you can debug it yourself.

Comment: I don't think you understood or read my comment. Are you saying `0` (Zero) equals false?? Also, why do you assume false is not a 'happy' result? I don't want to bother you. Thanks for your help. You got me a little bit further.